# Multiple main methods in Java

Tags: java

I expected the following code to have compiler issues but surprisingly it did not.

```
class p {
  static int a = 10;

  public static void main(String...args) {
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}

class child extends p {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(p.a+10);
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me:

a) Why the compiler is not complaining about multiple `main()` methods?

b) When I execute the above program from the command line I can see that only the class p's `main()` method is getting executed? What is the rationale behind that?

Comment: With regards to a): The `main` method is no different from any other method in Java, so the compiler treats it exactly as if you had two methods in different classes which just happened to have the same name. As far as b) goes, that will depend on how your `java` program is set up to choose a `main` method to execute. It is possible to configure the entry point into the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `main` method is just like any other method in Java, in that you can have the same name and signature on multiple classes.

It is special because to run anything in Java, you must specify the class containing the correct `main` method to run.

You must have specified class `p` to run:

```
$ java p
10
```

You could also specify class `child` to run:

```
$ java child
20
```

Compiling the `child` class gives you a warning:

> Child.java:3: warning: main(java.lang.String[]) in Child cannot override main(java.lang.String...) in P; overriding method is missing '...'

But we already know that `static` methods aren't inherited.  It's okay, we're not trying to inherit here anyway.

Also, `String...` is resolved to a `String[]` anyway, so the signatures are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

a) Why would the compiler complain about it? The methods are defined in 2 different classes, which is perfectly legal in Java (although probably not advisable to have the same field names common within the super and sub class).

b) It depends on which class you are running; you must be running the `p` class.

Comment: I think that responding to a question about "Why X?" with "Why not X?" is a bit condescending.

Answer (score 1):

main method acts as an entry point of your program. By declaring multiple main method in multiple class, you only declared multiple entry point and Java has no problem whatsoever with that.

Afterall when you run your program via command line you have to specify which class should be used as an entry point. Assuming your source file is called `p.java`, running your program with:

```
java p
```

Will cause p's main method to be invoked, whereas if you run your program with:

```
java child
```

The main method of `child` class will run instead of `p`